# PHP - How to Use ORDER BY and GROUP BY together

Tags: php, mysql, database, group-by

I created a table that contains `message, sender, to, time` I want group by sender and order by time this is my code

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `table` ORDER BY `time` GROUP BY `sender`")or die(mysql_error());
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$msg = $arr ['message'];
echo '</br>';
echo $msg;
}
```

that shows me this error

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY`sender`' at line 1`

So how to fix that problem?

Thanks 
Klaus

Comment: Try: SELECT * FROM  `table` GROUP BY `sender` ORDER BY `time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `table`  GROUP BY `sender` ORDER BY `time` ")or  die(mysql_error());
                                             // ^^--will be before order                    
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query);  // out of the while loop
    while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $msg = $arr['message'].'<br />';
           // ^^--remove space here
    echo $msg;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks now I want to echo msg order by `time` so how can I do this? Please

Comment: can you show an example of your table so i can see why its not ordering .?

Answer (score 2):

Note your precedence. After the results have been grouped , it should be ordered.

```
"SELECT * FROM  `table`  GROUP BY `sender` ORDER BY `time`"
```

Comment: how to order from greater to smaller?

Comment: add DESC at the end of query?

Comment: Thanks that was my problem

Comment: @Klaus Jasper: there is another problem - you cannot ask questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

how to use self-joins to get the max/min/something-n rows per group.

In your situation, it can be applied to the effect you want like so:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT group_id, MAX(`yourdate`) AS yourdate FROM tbl_name GROUP BY group_id)
AS x JOIN tbl_name USING (`group_id`,yourdate);
```